# how to upload a hybrid app to the google play?

Tags: c++, google-play, qml, apk, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing new features for this open source application, but i don't know how to create the APK for where i upload it to the store. does anyone have any idea on how to do this? i'm new to all of this so i appreciate the help.

this is the link for the source code https://github.com/guh/berrylan

I already tried looking on the documentation of Qml to see which one they used to developed this app

Comment: Did you try to search that in the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-deploying-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it is an open source application, you probably don't want to be uploading it to the store yourself, especially if you haven't discussed the process with the project leads.

- there can be only one application with the same package name / Application id for most app stores
- if you change the package name / application id it is incredibly confusing for users to know which app to use
- this means most App stores will block the app as a "copycat"
- even if the project is open source, if you want to replace the original app in the app store you need the signing key. Putting this signing key is a huge security mistake. If you did this then malware authors could compile a version of the app with "new features" that hurt the user or cost them money, getting the app banned. As a result most open source project don't keep the key in the project, and you'd need to contact the original uploader
- even if you had the key, For Google you'd need access to the Play store developer accounts. Which would mean having your gmail address added as trusted for the account owner. Which means you'd need to contact the project owner

In summary, even if an app is open source, publishing to a store is a big step which needs contact with the project owners if you don't want to get you or the app banned.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot Nick! i didn't realized that, but what i am doing is using the open source code and adding more features like a login, singup, news feed and so on, do i still need to take this as consideration? for example there source code will just be a little part of big app.

Comment: Open source libraries can be used in an android app if their license allows. But if this is what you wanted to do, you are essentially asking "how do I write an Android app" which is too vague a question for StackOverflow.